# How to set UIView delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, delegates, protocols

I have an UIViewController

```
class WelcomeViewController: UIViewController
```

and an UIView

```
class SignUpView: UIView
```

Now I want to set in my `WelcomeViewController` delegate of `SignUpView`:

```
protocol SegueDelegate {
    func runSegue(identifier: String)
}

class SignUpView: UIView { ... }
```

and connect it in

```
class WelcomeViewController: UIViewController, SegueDelegate {
```

how can I set in my WelcomeViiewController those delegate? When I'm trying to set:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    SignUpView.delegate = self
}
```

it returns me

```
Instance member 'delegate' cannot be used on type 'SignUpView'
```

how can I find a solution?

Comment: I assume the `delegate` property is not on the class-level but on the instance-level; am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to set delegate to a class. It should be an instance of the class i.e

```
let signUpView = SignUpView()
signUpView.delegate = self
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but why my delegate function does not call? Can you please look at my code? It's short - http://pastebin.com/7J5bSTzd

Comment: Everything seems fine, can you check if signUp is really called and you have a segue with id "goToMainPage"

Comment: it does not even call my delegate function. Yes, I have such a segue

Comment: is signUp function called properly?

Comment: yes, those function calls successfully, but the delegate part - not

Comment: Oh I guess the problem is, signUpView should be an outlet. It means that you should create an outlet for this view by dragging from storyboard to view controller. it should be like @IBOutlet weak var signUpView: SignUpView! in the definition. Then set this inside viewDidLoad as signUpView.delegate = self

Comment: the problem is that those `SignUpView` is a UIView XIB. So, I cannot create an outlet. Or I can?)

Comment: then you have to load the nib via loadNibNamed method

Comment: like this: `WelcomeViewController(nibName: "SignUpView", bundle: nil)`? It does not work, too

Comment: Currently you are already using this SignUpView with your view controller. How did you make it?

Comment: I have a WelcomeViewController and the UIView XIB. When I click on button on the WelcomeVC I run a function with `self.view.addSubview(xib)`. So my view becomes a xib. Later, when I click on a button on my UIView XIB, I want to segue from the WelcomeController to the MainViewController

Comment: Can you share all welcomeviewcontroller class, pieces of code doesn't make sense

Comment: Remove variable a from the class and just add signUpView.delegate = self in viewDidLoad that would be enough

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105238/discussion-between-john-doe-and-yunus-eren-guzel).

Answer (score 0):

What would be the point in doing that? If you want to navigate from one View to another, just add that Segue in Storyboard with an Identifier, so you can call `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("IdentifierOfSegue", sender: self)`

Answer (score 0):

Create a weak property in SignUpView of that delegate(protocol) and name it other than delegate

then you can set and use it.

Comment: Yes, it works, but why my delegate function does not call? Can you please look at my code? It's short - http://pastebin.com/7J5bSTzd

Comment: Please rename it segueDelegate and then check

Comment: this `var delegate: SegueDelegate?` variable name or where? Sorry I did not catch it

Comment: var segueDelegate : SegueDelegate?

Comment: then set SignUpView. segueDelegate = self

Comment: is your view's name SignUpView in ViewController?

Comment: then set SignUpView. segueDelegate = self

Comment: yes, I know about that :) No, it does not, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the developers saying "you can just do that via segue"  but
the problem is you didn't declare a delegate var in the SignUpView class
so you can implement it in the signIn , if you declared it please write the line of code for me in a comment to check it
for now ... 
I can suggest that you make a subview to be a parent class then override 
which method you want to call 
and you need to declare the delegate var as an optional (so you won't have 
a memory cycle) like the following line ...

```
var delegate: SegueDelegate?
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's solve this for people in need whom could need a solution when reading this issue:

In your UIView:

```
class SignUpView: UIView
```

you need to add:

```
var delegate : SegueDelegate?
```

Now, still in your class `SignUpView`, you need to add the function you want to delegate, just like this:

```
func runSegue(identifier: String) {
    delegate?.runSegue(identifier)
}
```

This will call your delegate:

```
protocol SegueDelegate {
    func runSegue(identifier: String)
}
```

Now, in your `ViewController`, you should have your `SignUpView` somewhere (created programmatically or linked through Storyboard / XIB).

In your `viewDidLoad`function, add: `signUpView.delegate = self`.

Don't forget to add `SegueDelegate`in your class heritage.